# Crash with Facebook login after cancelling Google Play Games login (and vice versa)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games, facebook-unity-sdk

On Android (4.3), if I start logging into Google Play Services and cancel with the back button, and then start logging into Facebook, my app immediately crashes with this output:

> 06-05 18:02:43.321  6393  6531 F chromium_net:
>   external/chromium/base/threading/thread_local_posix.cc:18: 
>   [0605/180243:FATAL:thread_local_posix.cc(18)] Check failed: error == 0
>   (11 vs. 0)
>
> 06-05 18:02:43.321  6393  6531 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
>   at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 6531 (WebViewCoreThre)
>
> 06-05 18:02:43.331  6393  6393 D WebView : loadUrlImpl: called
>
> 06-05 18:02:43.341  2345  2472 D STATUSBAR-StatusBarManagerService:
>   manageDisableList what=0x0 pkg=WindowManager.LayoutParams
>
> 06-05 18:02:43.361  2345  2473 D LockPatternUtils: isPcwEnable = null
>
> 06-05 18:02:43.361  1935  1996 I SurfaceFlinger: id=3595 createSurf
>   (1x1),1 flag=4, MoginActivi
>
> 06-05 18:02:43.366  2345  5574 D LockPatternUtils: isPcwEnable = null
>
> 06-05 18:02:43.381  5714  5714 I DEBUG   : *****     ***** ***
>
> ---
>
> 06-05 18:02:43.381  5714  5714 I DEBUG   : Build fingerprint:
>   'samsung/m0xx/m0:4.3/JSS15J/I9300XXUGNB6:user/release-keys'
>
> 06-05 18:02:43.381  5714  5714 I DEBUG   : Revision: '12'
>
> 06-05 18:02:43.381  5714  5714 I DEBUG   : pid: 6393, tid: 6531, name:
>   WebViewCoreThre  >>> com.XX.Test <<<
>
> 06-05 18:02:43.381  5714  5714 I DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1
>   (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadbaad
>
> 06-05 18:02:43.381  2345  5574 D LockPatternUtils: isPcwEnable = null
>
> 06-05 18:02:43.391  2345  2473 D LockPatternUtils: isPcwEnable = null
>
> 06-05 18:02:43.736  2588  2588 D STATUSBAR-NetworkController:
>   onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength: 9 -1 -1 -1 -1
>   -1 -1 99 -140 -20 -200 -1 2147483647 gsm|lte 0x3 level=3
>
> 06-05 18:02:44.211  5714  5714 I DEBUG   :     r0 00000027  r1
>   00000000  r2 00000000  r3 deadbaad

If I start the Facebook login and cancel, and then start the Google Play Games login, O also get the crash.

I'm using Unity 4.6.5, Facebook SDK 6.2.2, and Google Play Games Plugin for Unity 0.9.20. Both logins work fine, unless if I attempt them both.

How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 2):

You can see in your crash this line:

> 06-05 18:02:43.321 6393 6531 F libc : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at **0xdeadbaad** (code=1), thread 6531 (WebViewCoreThre)

I'd refer you [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak) where you can see:

> 0xDEADBAAD ("dead bad") is used by the Android libc abort() function when native heap corruption is detected.

You'll need to provide a lot more info about your app and crash for this to be solved properly. I'd look into the WebView that you are opening (or maybe Unity is creating for you?). Please generate a bug report after the crash (It's in the Developers Settings) and email it to yourself, there you might find a Tombstone which might give you a lot more info (if you have the tombstone dereferencer, or whatever it's called, I forget).

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess: Do you have a 'on complete' callback that does something to your UI?

Even if you abort/go back the process will continue unless you do something to cancel it. If it continues and the view is changed, your onComplete-method might access variables that are no longer available since you changed your view.